# What is negative red/positive blue chakra?

Tags: naruto

Ok, so when Killer B was teaching Naruto the tailed beast bomb rasengan thing he mentioned the negative red chakra and the positive blue chakra. What does that mean? I thought there was only one type of chakra..

They haven't mentioned any negative or positive chakra before have they? Then what is it?

Answer (score 4):

At first I found your question really confusing, but while answering another question I figured out the answer for this one.

---

In the manga, [Yin Release](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Yin_Release), which is a type of chakra nature, was depicted as black but **red** in the anime.

In the manga, [Yang Release](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Yang_Release), another chakra nature, was depicted as white but **blue** in anime.

**Yin Release:**

> - can be used to create form out of nothingness
> - genjutsu falls under the broad category of Yin Release.
> - Yin chakra is also part of the tailed beasts' chakra.
> - Yin Release can be used offensively when combined with senjutsu. However, it is unknown what exact role the Yin Release fulfils in said technique.

**Yang Release:**

> - can be used to breathe life into form.
> - Yang chakra is also part of the tailed beasts' chakra.
> - Whenever Naruto is in Nine-Tails Chakra Mode, Wood Release techniques react to the Yang chakra's vitalising properties and mature into full-grown trees within a matter of seconds, either through contact or close proximity.

**Positive/Negative Chakra:**

- It's another differentiation in chakra, but it's not the same as Yin-Yang.
- Black/Red chakra, Yin Release, is negative.
- White/blue chakra, Yang Release, is positive.
- The Bijuu Bomb is made from combining negative and positive chakra, not Yin and Yang.

---

Also, there is not just **one** chakra type.

[image]

Comment: so will thy explain this stuff later in the anime?

Comment: @MartianCactus, thy? "So will your explain this stuff later in the anime?".

Comment: Crystal release is not in the chart because its not canon on the same level as the others. The only user of it was a filler character. And if you truly never heard of Positive and Negative chakra, then why did you not read the section pointed out by OP where they were mentioned?

Comment: @Ryan, sorry. Just edited my answer. And I said I never hear of it before, but I had, I  just forgot.